# Is there a way to access an Azure route table's routes with a PowerShell script?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

For example, let's say I had a routetable called "MyRouteTable", and this route table had ten routes. I'd like to assign each of these routes a new NextHopAddress.

Is there a way to use a PowerShell script to get these routes programmatically so that I can iterate through them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all the routes name using command like:

```
$table = Get-AzureRmRouteTable -ResourceGroupName "TestGP" -Name "routetable"

# All the routes name will be stored in $routes
$routes = @()
foreach ($routeName in $table.Routes)
{
    $routes += $i.Name
}

# Custom code here
```

Then you can loop the routes name and update route like:

```
foreach ($routeName in $routes)
{
    Set-AzureRmRouteConfig -Name $routeName -RouteTable $table -AddressPrefix <address prefix> -NextHopType <type>
}

# Sets the goal state for route table
Set-AzureRmRouteTable -RouteTable $table
```